# is there any way to get a customer profile in shopify?

Tags: reactjs, shopify, shopify-api-node

https://help.shopify.com/en/api/getting-started/authentication/oauth

I am using Shopify login for my app and it almost works but I am stuck getting a customer profile from the access token.

https://{shop}.myshopify.com/admin/oauth/access_token

I use this API and now I have access token so how can I get data from that token?

Comment: Read the documentation.... There might be more APIs for that...

Comment: Check this one...but it is only for Shopify Plus Clients.  https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/plus/user

Comment: @Vishal this is only for private app not for public app if you have any refrences for public apps please share with me asap.And thanks for responding on my post.

Comment: @HimanshuBansal I follow this documentation https://help.shopify.com/en/api/getting-started/authentication/oauth I almost succeed from there.
{
  "access_token": "f85632530bf277ec9ac6f649fc327f17",
  "scope": "write_orders,read_customers"
}
but I stuck after that there is no clarifying documentation that how to retrieve customer details from that access token or scope and no other API is given there so we can hit that and the user details fetched.So if you have any solution about this problem please let me know asap.Any link,API,or any other resource.And thanks for replying on my post.

Comment: @DeepanshuGarg  the read_customers scope is used to manage the customers who buy/purchases on the Shopify website and I think, you are looking for the user ( who will install your app) details....correct me If I'm wrong!

Comment: @Vishal Actually I want details of owner who create that app or store.

Comment: @DeepanshuGarg Okay, let me take a look and will get back to you soon. You can check the shop.json API   https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/store-properties/shop

Comment: @Vishal Okay,and I'll check this link but that is not match with the problem because there is no use of access token and i have only that to hit any api.

Comment: @Vishal please look I want that type of json.Through that access token

{
  "access_token": "f85632530bf277ec9ac6f649fc327f17",
  "scope": "write_orders,read_customers",
  "expires_in": 86399,
  "associated_user_scope": "write_orders",
  "associated_user": {
    "id": 902541635,
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Smith",
    "email": "john@example.com",
    "email_verified": true,
    "account_owner": true,
    "locale": "en",
    "collaborator": false
  }
}

Comment: @DeepanshuGarg, from where you did get this JSON  { "access_token": "f85632530bf277ec9ac6f649fc327f17", "scope": "write_orders,read_customers", "expires_in": 86399, "associated_user_scope": "write_orders", "associated_user": { "id": 902541635, "first_name": "John", "last_name": "Smith", "email": "john@example.com", "email_verified": true, "account_owner": true, "locale": "en", "collaborator": false } } . Also, the token will required to access this API https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/store-properties/shop

Comment: @Vishal did you see this link or not if you saw then you can check in 3 step this response provide. (https://help.shopify.com/en/api/getting-started/authentication/oauth) And I was checked the shop api but i am encountering this type of error again and again.({
    "errors": "[API] Invalid API key or access token (unrecognized login or wrong password)"
})